# Implement Quick sort algorithm with partition of 3 elements,

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

How to convert this Quick sort algorithm into partition of 3 ,5,7,9 and 11 elements?

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define size 50
void swap(int *x,int *y)
{
int temp;
temp = *x;
*x = *y;
*y = temp;
}

int partition(int i,int j )
{
return((i+j) /2);
}

void quicksort(int list[],int m,int n)
{
int key,i,j,k;
if( m < n)
{
k = partition(m,n);
swap(&list[m],&list[k]);
key = list[m];
i = m+1;
j = n;
while(i <= j)
{
while((i <= n) && (list[i] <= key))
i++;
while((j >= m) && (list[j] > key))
j--;
if( i < j)
swap(&list[i],&list[j]);
}

swap(&list[m],&list[j]);
quicksort(list,m,j-1);
quicksort(list,j+1,n);
}
}
void printlist(int list[],int n)
{
int i;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
printf("%d\t",list[i]);
}

void main()
{
int n,i;
int list[size];


printf("How many numbers do you want to enter");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("Enter the numbers you want to sort");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
scanf("%d",&list[i]);
}


printf("The list before sorting is:\n");
printlist(list,n);
quicksort(list,0,n-1);
printf("The list after sorting using quicksort algorithm:\n");
printlist(list,n);
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: The partition phase in quicksort consists in rearranging the elements of the sequence to be sorted to the left or right of the chosen pivot, depending on them being smaller or larger than the pivot, respectively. Not sure what is meant by "partition of _x_", though.

Comment: If you after gregg's answer (and the reading) still have questions left, either add them to the question (if they are related), or create a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your C++ teacher simply has a poor choice of wording.  "partition of 3 elements" almost certainly means: choose the pivot element by picking the median of the first, middle and last elements -- this is the most common coding technique and has good properties when the array is already sorted.

Extrapolate that definition for 5, 7, 9, 11.

Comment: i think its not poor wording choice but something very tricky .

Comment: Or perhaps it is a horse instead of a zebra: http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=partition+of+3+medians&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: Ah, I had thought the idea is to partition in 4/6/8 parts instead of only two.

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning is an essential part of the quicksort algorithm.  Review [the algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) to understand what partitioning is. Good luck.

Comment: right, but could you elaborate on what a "partition of _x_ elements" is?

Comment: yeah  i know when pivot got its right position  partitioning occurs. but again i don't know the meaning of partition of x elements.